# How to query with Contains on a concatenated string in Entity Framework

Tags: linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

My Serial object contains the following values

```
string Class
int Product
int Code
```

Together they form a Serial Number. Note that 2 of them are integers.

```
Class + Product.ToString() + "-" + Code.ToString()
```

I am attempting to filter based on a string. Example:

```
serials = _context.Serials.AsQueryable();

serials = serials.Where(serial => serial.Class.Contains(searchText));
```

I am looking to perform a `.Contains()` on the concatenated `SerialNumber`. How would I perform this in EF Core?

Something like this does not work. Throwing an error about query not being translated.

```
serials = serials.Where(serial => string.Concat(serial.ProductClass, serial.ProductNumber.ToString(), serial.CodeNumber.ToString()).Contains(searchText))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only [string.Concat(string, string)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netcore-3.1#System_String_Concat_System_String_System_String_) overload is supported.

Use `+` operator instead:

```
.Where(serial => 
    (serial.ProductClass + serial.ProductNumber.ToString() + serial.CodeNumber.ToString())
    .Contains(searchText))
```

Comment: Such an easy fix. Thank you!